Android adding Settings icon gear to App Info
I am working with Xamarin Forms and trying to add a Settings icon gear to my App Info, this is what I have tried:
Added this to AndroidManifest.xml inside the application node:
<activity
            android:name=".ui.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="Settings"
            android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.NOTIFICATION_PREFERENCES" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

Created a file called SettingsActivity.cs to my root and added this code, I get an error:

"The name 'AddPreferencesFromResource' does not exist in the current context"):

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Preferences;

namespace RegistrationApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "SettingsActivity")]
    [Obsolete]
    public class SettingsActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);

            // Create your application here
            AddPreferencesFromResource(Resource.Xml.preferences);
        }
    }
}

And I created an xml folder inside Resources and created a file called preferences.xml inside my new xml folder and added this code:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="General">

        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="edit_text_preference"
            android:title="EditText Preference"
            android:summary="This is an EditText preference"
            android:dialogTitle="Enter your text" />

        <!-- Add more preferences as needed -->

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>

I get the error "The name 'AddPreferencesFromResource' does not exist in the current context" so changed this:
public class SettingsActivity : Activity to this public class SettingsActivity : PreferenceActivity and that gets ride of the error, but still no Settings gear in App Info...is there something I am doing wrong?
My goal is to have Settings inside App Info for the user to be able to change.
